# What are the differences between Vanilla Perl and Strawberry Perl?

Tags: perl, winapi, strawberry-perl

[Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) is "Open Source Perl for Windows that is exactly the same
as Perl everywhere else". [Vanilla Perl](http://vanillaperl.com/) "provides a Perl distribution that is as close to the Perl core as possible." Strawberry Perl is built on Vanilla Perl.

Both distributions come with a C compiler so that perl modules from CPAN that use XS can be built.

What are the differences between Strawberry Perl and Vanilla Perl?

Comment: One's from pink oysters, the other's from white oysters. :)

Comment: If only there were a Neapolitan Perl, that bundled Strawberry, Vanilla and ActiveState Perls all together :)

Comment: @Ether: 'fraid not; Strawberry is a superset of Vanilla, and Chocolate will be a superset of Strawberry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just read the explanation on the [Vanilla Perl homepage](http://vanillaperl.com/)

> **Vanilla Perl Series**
>
> The Vanilla Perl series provides a
>   Perl distribution that is as close to
>   the Perl core as possible. If
>   necessary, it may include
>   win32-specific fixes.
>
> Vanilla Perl is experimental and is
>   not intended for production purposes.
>   It is targeted to master-level Win32
>   Perl developers and those who wish to
>   experiment with building their own
>   custom Win32 Perl distributions.
>   Vanilla Perl releases are numbered
>   only as sequential 'builds' and will
>   not follow any alpha/beta/release
>   plan. This means incremental builds
>   may be less stable than previous
>   builds as new release configurations
>   are tested.

And

> **Strawberry Perl Series**
>
> The purpose of the Strawberry Perl
>   series is to provide a more practical
>   Win32 Perl release for experienced
>   Perl developers to experiment and test
>   the installation of various CPAN
>   modules under Win32 conditions, and to
>   provide a useful platform for
>   experienced Perl developers to start
>   doing real work.
>
> **In addition to the modules in Vanilla
>   Perl, Strawberry will also include the
>   entire dependency tree for
>   Bundle::CPAN, as well as an additional
>   set of upgraded versions of dual
>   CPAN/core modules that have
>   win32-specific fixes.**

Comment: Ahh... "the entire dependency tree for Bundle::CPAN"; I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that often Perl distros come with non-core modules. ActiveState in particular is known for doing this. The non-core modules improve usability quite a bit.

Vanilla is the core distro. Strawberry comes with the standard non-standard modules. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As per [Vanilla Perl home page](http://vanillaperl.com/):

- In addition to the modules in Vanilla Perl, Strawberry will also include the entire dependency tree for [Bundle::CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Bundle::CPAN), as well as an additional set of upgraded versions of dual CPAN/core modules that have win32-specific fixes.

From Wiki:

- Strawberry Perl is part of the Vanilla Perl Project